# What is the practical application of argsort()

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Recently I came across `argsort()` and I figured out it will return the indexes of the sorted sequence.But I am not clear at one point, if we are using it to sort an array why not simply use sort().

```
In [77]: import numpy as np

In [79]: arr = np.array([4,5,1,7,3])

In [80]: arr1 = np.sort(arr)

In [81]: arr1
Out[81]: array([1, 3, 4, 5, 7])

In [84]: arr2 = np.argsort(arr)

In [85]: arr2
Out[85]: array([2, 4, 0, 1, 3])
```

What are the benefits of argsort over normal sort? Where can we use its return result i.e indexes of sorted sequence. Anyone having idea of its application in real world.

Answer (score 0):

Numpy lets you use an array of indices as an index to an array:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([4,5,1,7,3])
>>> arr1 = np.sort(arr)
>>> arr2 = np.argsort(arr)
>>> arr1 = arr[arr2]
>>> arr1 = np.sort(arr)
>>> arr1 == arr[arr2]
array([ True,  True,  True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

This can  useful for implementing a decorate-sort-undecorate routine like Python's native `sort` function does if you give it a `key` function - for example, to sort by the *square* of each value instead of the value itself you could:

```
>>> arr = np.array([4,-5,1,-7,3])
>>> arr[np.argsort(arr**2)]
array([ 1,  3,  4, -5, -7])
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ivc...but what is the advantage of sorting through indices not directly by using value. If i am right will it be helpful in the scenarios where we don't know the actual data but still with indices we can sort the array.

Comment: @abhinavkumar see the last example in my answer; `argsort` combined with fancy indexing lets you use a sort key, similarly to how the builtin `sort` can take a `key` function.